# Non-LINQ implementations of Union, Intersect, and Except

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, union, intersection

LINQ to objects has the incredibly useful `Union`, `Intersect`, and `Except` methods. Sadly, there's a client I'm doing work for and they are mandating .NET 2.0 so LINQ is not an option. I looked through the reflected code and it didn't reverse well at all.

Is there a .NET 2.0 library or easy implementation of `Union`, `Intersect`, and `Except`?

Comment: @wawa: If by "the linq dll" you mean System.Core, I would *strongly* advise against trying to use a .NET 3.5 assembly bolted on to a normal .NET 2 assembly. It *may* work fine, but I'm 99.9% sure it's not a supported scenario. Using a separate library (e.g. LINQBridge) is a much better bet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any reason not to use [LINQBridge](http://linqbridge.googlecode.com)? Get your LINQ to Objects goodness while still targeting .NET 2.0 :)

Comment: These still seem to be extension methods. Will I need to write another layer to turn them into non-extensions or is that already built in also?

Comment: You can use VS2008 and the C# 3 compiler, which handles all the extension methods just fine, and still target the 2.0 runtime. But even so you wouldn't need to actually write another layer, those are just plain static methods decorated with some attribute to make the compiler magic work.